# Need ASP.Net core 3.1 reporting library(Have to show pie chart in word document)

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

I tried with AspNetCore.Reporting along with RDLC.Grid is showing good.But while trying PIE chart it showing error.Please assist me to proceed forward.

Please look the attached image

[Generated Word_ASPNETCORE.Reporting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bt2W.png)

Comment: Can you provide your exact requirements type of project like web,winform, or something else? if its web you can use refere this 
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/pie-charts

Comment: I wanna plot the pie chart in word document. It's asp net core web api.so no UI we can check in swagger alone,need to be download the word document in byte stream as response

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.